# I need to convert field to date. Sample data: 09-19-1943, 9-5-1930, 04-07-1971

Tags: ms-access

My data has a field `[patient dob]` which contains entries such as:

```
09-19-1943
9-5-1930
04-07-1971
10/11/2006
8/7/1981
```

EDIT - *I want to get these strings converted to date/times that I can calculate against.*

If all data was mm dd yyyy with either / or - separating the numbers I would have the solution to that. I also have the solution if the number of digits are not always fixed. What I do not know how to do it look for either - or / when the number of digits is not fixed.

Right now I am using

```
DateOfBirth: Format(((Left([patient dob],2)) & "/" & (Mid([Patient DOB],4,2)) & "/" & (Right([patient dob],4))),"Short Date")
```

which is what made me notice the number of digits problem.

Is there any trick I can use to evaluate for / or - and then parse on which ever is found?

Comment: Well how about that - I need a date/time field that I can calculate against. (I thought Format was the way to use a query to convert string to date/time; I'll go back to the drawing board on that one - and I'll edit the question!)

Comment: @HansUp - that works! *IIf(IsDate([patient dob]),CDate([patient dob]),"")* **Thanks very much**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Format()` returns a string, so you're not *converting* `[Patient DOB]` to date datatype.

Consider `CDate()` to cast your date string to actual Date/Time datatype.  It doesn't care whether day and month have a leading zero for values < 10, and also doesn't care whether the separator is `-` or `/`.

These all return the same Date/Time value:

- `CDate("04-07-1971")`
- `CDate("04/07/1971")`
- `CDate("4-7-1971")`
- `CDate("4/7/1971")`

Regarding the expression in your comment, consider returning Null instead of an empty string when `[patient dob]` does not contain a string which represents a valid date:

```vb
IIf(IsDate([patient dob]), CDate([patient dob]), Null)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I will switch to Null